# AS3 Embed access child movieclips

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

So I am using this code to embed my .swf file. I am creating classes for each asset in my library.

```
[Embed('assets/assets.swf', symbol='game.menu.levels')]
public static const LEVELS_MENU:Class;
```

It works just fine but how can I access a child element multiple depths down?

I have this thus far:

```
this.object = new R.LEVELS_MENU();
var child_element:MovieClip = 
    this.object.getChildByName("child_element") as MovieClip;
```

Is there a better way than doing this:

```
var child_child_element:DisplayObjectContainer = 
        DisplayObjectContainer(
                child_element.getChildByName("child_child_element")
        );
var child_child_child_element:DisplayObjectContainer = 
        DisplayObjectContainer(
                child_child_element.getChildByName("child_child_child_element")
        );
```

Is there a way I could do it with dot syntax as such:

```
child_element.child_child_element.child_child_child_element...
```

Comment: I think I have just realized that it would be easier to just import as SWC then pull the assets that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I am aware.

There might be a workaround.

If you created those children from the Flash IDE, you should be able to access them directly via references like this:

```
MovieClip(this.object).child1.child2.child3.child4;
```

Or if you are doing that MovieClip initialization manually (new operator) inside the swf, you can also create those references manually like this:

```
child["child_child_name"] = child_child;
```

Though this won't matter for movieclips, as they are dynamic, so you can just do:

```
child.child_child_name = child_child;
```

These last two are inside .swf code of course;

Comment: Hmmm I've tried all three of those previously and they all result in an Error #1009. Keep in mind this is in Flash Builder so I am embedding the .swf.

Comment: Okay your solution is correct, I just needed to add my assets as a SWF and also export to actionscript all of the child elements. Once I did that it worked just as you have above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your main document Class declares the instances (i.e. "declare stage instances automatically" is off, then just cast the swf to the document Class.

So,

```
var yourSwf:YourSwf = new LEVELS_MENU() as YourSwf;
var mc = yourSwf.child1;
```

You should probably consider exposing an interface on your main document Class, so that other Classes don't need to know it's specifically a YourSwf.  For an example of this, check out http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/example-of-casting-contets-of-swfloader.html .

Note that you are setting yourself up for a world of hurt, using a static Class where Classes are coupled to it to supply their own dependencies.  Please at least consider migrating to the Abstract Factory pattern (http://www.as3dp.com/2009/01/25/actionscript-30-abstract-factory-design-pattern-multiple-products-and-factories/)